# How to create an NSDictionary in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I want to create an `NSDictionary` like this type:

```json
"zones": 
{
    {
        "zoneId": "1",
        "locations": 
        {
            {
                "locId": "1",
                "locZoneId": "1",
                "locLatitude": "33.68506785633641",
                "locLongitude": "72.97488212585449"
            },
            {
                "locId": “2”,
                "locZoneId": "1",
                "locLatitude": "33.68506785633641",
                "locLongitude": "72.97488212585449"
            },
            {
                "locId": “3”,
                "locZoneId": "1",
                "locLatitude": "33.68506785633641",
                "locLongitude": "72.97488212585449"
            },
        }
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What would you like to accomplish? Do you want to deserialize a structure like this?

Answer (score 88):

You should use a combination of arrays and dictionaries.

**Dictionaries** are initialized like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{ key : value, key2 : value2};
```

**Arrays** are initialized like this:

```
NSArray *array = @[Object1, Object2]
```

Answer (score 10):

### Objective-C the correct, typed way of creating a dictionary.

The following has a strongly typed `key` as `NSString` and the `value` as `NSNumber`.

You should always set the types where you can, because by making it strongly typed the compiler will stop you from making common errors and it works better with Swift:

```
NSDictionary<NSString *, NSNumber *> *numberDictionary;
```

but in the case above, we need to store an array in the dictionary, so it will be:

```
NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *dataDictionary;
```

which allows the value to be of any type.